# cloudfoundry - vmc register error with external uri

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry, vmc

I installed cloudfoundry with the -D option to change the default domain. Cloudfoundry installs fine and starts but when I try to vmc in I get an error:

`swampfox@swampcf:~$ vmc target api.mydomain.com`
`Successfully targeted to [http://api.mydomain.com]`

`swampfox@swampcf:~$ vmc register --email emailid@gmail.com --passwd mypass
Creating New User: OK
Attempting login to [http://api.mydomain.com]
Problem with login to 'http://api.mydomain.com', target refused connection (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known), try again or register for an account.`

`swampfox@swampcf:~$ vmc register --email emailid@gmail.com --passwd mypass
Creating New User: Error 100: Bad request`

Can someone help. I need to have the external uri or this is useless for me.

This works fine if I take the default api.vcap.me but it only works on that vm and is not accessable from other infrastructure which is pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. There is a bug in vmc-0.3.21. Backed it down to vmc-0.3.18 and everything works now.

Whoof! How to open a bug against vmc?

Comment: You can file bugs for the Cloud Foundry project at https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net

Answer (score 0):

When you have tried api.vcap.me, did you do this by just changing the endpoint address in config/cloud_controller.yml? If so, it may be worth checking to see if the setup did set the endpoint correctly in all the other configuration files, uaa.yml especially in this case as you are having issues with login.

I have always used the standard configuration (api.vcap.me) and then manually changed the endpoint in all the configuration files using sed, for example, from the config directory;

```
sed -i 's/\.vcap\.me/.newdomain.com/g' *.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I initially installed with default api.vcap.me. Then i wiped out the guest an completely reinstalled with -D mydomain.com. I have subsquently installed another CF on a different guest with api.vcap.me for comparison.

Checked the config /home/cfadmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/uaa.yml and there is no reverence to api.swampnet.com or api.vcap.me.

Just a quick note. I can successfully login from an external domain like emc.com but i cannot login on the local machine or a machine in the same subnet. Whoof!

I noticed that the controller had external uris false so I set them to ture but that made no difference. If I set them to true on the api.vcap.me instance will that allow me to push and app with an external uri?

Comment: so I found that by changing the external uri parms in config from false to true I could push an app using an external uri. however, I still cannot login to the CF with api.mydomain.com from the same subnet (which is quite pizaar to me).

Comment: What about the vcap.me in deploy.json?

Comment: Ok! I completely reinstalled and ran the sed but now it does not connect at all. Here is what I get -

Comment: swampfox@swampcf0:~/cloudfoundry/$ vmc target api.mydomain.com

Comment: however if i go to IE and display http://api.mydomain.com I get the following "Welcome to VMware's Cloud Application Platform"