# Cloud Foundry On Azure VM

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

I've successfully installed VCAP on my ubuntu 12.04 on azure . Now I plan to access it on public .

Information about it is :

**DNS :
meruvian354.cloudapp.net**

**HOST NAME :
meruvian354**

**PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS (VIP) : 168.62.193.163**

**INTERNAL IP ADDRESS : 10.76.198.28**

My target is generate automaticaly domain **"myapp".meruvian354.cloudapp.net** and vcap on make it online.

How do I have to set it on cloud_controller.yml ?
and Do I have to set configuration on

Answer (score 2):

You need a wildcard domain pointing at the public IP address, I can see you have meruvian354.cloudapp.net registered as the api url for the cloud controller as I was able to register an account!

If you registered mydomain.com you would have to create a wildcarded "A" domain record for that domain and point it to the public IP address. You would then need to either create a new deployment using the -D option to specify the new domain or adjust the configuration of the current deployment using a tool like sed, see this question for another example;

[cloudfoundry - vmc register error with external uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531777/cloudfoundry-vmc-register-error-with-external-uri)

Comment: So I have to configure it with Wildcard A on Azure ,  

redirect it on my Public IP address.

Then change all domain setting on vcap master with 

"sed -i 's/\.vcap\.me/.newdomain.com/g' *.yml"

Will it make my applications automatically have a domain too , which I can access it from internet directly ?

Comment: Yes, you will obviously need to change the sed command appropriately for your current configuration. Once you have done that, VCAP will handle request for all cname level domain names including apps deployed to that instance.

Comment: I've successfully change meruvia354.cloudapp.net domain to paas.azure4j.us and set it as api url. 
I've successfully give a domain to my application too . 
thanks sir. :)
But I cant access it directly from internet .
what should i do ?

Comment: Ok, it looks fine and in fact I have deployed a node.js app to it! However, you don't seem to have the wildcard DNS set up correctly. I deployed an application called dantest-node, this means that dantest-node.azure4j.us should go to the VCAP instance, however, it does not.

Comment: Oh .. I check that your apps run good on it .
Thanks to contribute us .
I've tried many times for wildcard ., but have not been successfull ,maybe because I'm a beginner :).

Do you have a tutorial or guide that is right for it?

Comment: It depends to be honest on your DNS provider, just google for "Wildcard DNS <your-dns-provider-name-here>" and you should find a tutorial. If you could mark this question as answered, that would be great! :-)